# Is this formula for mean curvature always valid?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curvature, minimal-surfaces

I read that mean curvature $H=\frac{En+Gl-2Fm}{2(EG-F^2)}$, where $E=\mathbf{x}_u\cdot\mathbf{x}_v$, $F=\mathbf{x}_u\cdot\mathbf{x}_v$, and $G=\mathbf{x}_v\cdot\mathbf{x}_v$ are the coefficients of the first fundamental form, and $l$, $m$, and $n$ are the coefficients of the second fundamental form. But for this formula to make sense, we should always have $EG=(\mathbf{x}_u\cdot\mathbf{x}_v)(\mathbf{x}_v\cdot\mathbf{x}_v)\neq(\mathbf{x}_u\cdot\mathbf{x}_v)(\mathbf{x}_u\cdot\mathbf{x}_v)={F}^2$. But since the dot product is associative and commutative, don't we actually have equality here, implying that the denominator of the formula is 0? I'm very confused by this.

EDIT: I now realize the dot product is not associative. But still, do we always have that $EG\neq{F}^2$? If so, then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because dot product, inherited from $\Bbb R^3$, is a positive definite bilinear form, so $EG-F^2>0$. Alternatively, $EG-F^2$ is the square of the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\mathbf x_u$ and $\mathbf x_v$, and these vectors are linearly independent.

By the way, it makes no sense to say dot product is associative, as dot product of two vectors is a scalar, not another vector.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that about the dot product, thanks.

Comment: It's still unclear, though, why the dot product being a positive definite bilinear form means $EG-F^2>0$. You can say that to show $u\cdot{v}>0$ if $u\neq{v}$ or something involving the bilinearity, but why does either imply $EG\neq{F^2}$? Also, why is this quantity equal to $|\mathbf{x}_u\times\mathbf{x}_v|^2$ (as you are suggesting with the comment about a the area of the parallelogram)?

Comment: This is a standard linear algebra fact. Maybe the easiest way to see it is to note that positive definiteness is equivalent to positivity of both eigenvalues of the (symmetric) matrix, and the determinant is the product of those eigenvalues. For the parallelogram fact, I refer you to pp. 40-41 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).